# How to deal with versioning files that are not types recognized by sharepoint

Tags: check-out, check-in

We store files in sharepoint that are not office documents (PDFs, Quickbooks files, that kind of thing). I would like to be able to check them out, modify them, and upload a new version, check in and have proper version of the changes on such a file.

How do you accomplish this? Either using the web interface or WebDAV.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Versioning itself is controlled on the Document Library so as long as that is enabled it will enforce those requirements.  However, getting those files into SharePoint will most likely require manually replacing them and checking them in and out via the UI.

One option that *sometimes* works is to map a drive to a SharePoint folder and then save updates to that folder, though usually you have to disable a lot of options, like requiring a checkout before making updates.  You would have to experiment to see if this is even workable for you.

Comment: Thanks. How do you replace them? That is part of my question. Just upload a new file and choose to replace it?

Comment: That's all there is to it.